# Error build IOS release using React Native

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios, ipa

I have developed a full app using React Native and it is also working fine for Android but this is my first time doing in iOS and when I tried to build on iOS then the app builds successfully but when the app opens in the emulator then in Xcode it shows the following error

```html
2018-03-24 18:15:03.964 [error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Native module cannot be null.
2018-03-24 18:15:03.966535+0530 VwWoocommerceApp[14134:150196] Native module cannot be null.
2018-03-24 18:15:03.969 [fatal][tid:com.facebook.react.ExceptionsManagerQueue] Unhandled JS Exception: Native module cannot be null.
2018-03-24 18:15:03.969554+0530 VwWoocommerceApp[14134:150193] Unhandled JS Exception: Native module cannot be null.
2018-03-24 18:15:03.970 [error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)
2018-03-24 18:15:03.971150+0530 VwWoocommerceApp[14134:150196] Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)
2018-03-24 18:15:03.995465+0530 VwWoocommerceApp[14134:150193] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RCTFatalException: Unhandled JS Exception: Native module cannot be null.', reason: 'Unhandled JS Exception: Native module cannot be null., stack:
t@68:276
<unknown>@610:127
d@2:755
<unknown>@609:654
d@2:755
<unknown>@307:1275
d@2:755
<unknown>@306:141
d@2:755
<unknown>@12:42
d@2:755
n@2:326
global code@612:8
'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001111cc12b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010fabef41 objc_exception_throw + 48
2   VwWoocommerceApp                    0x000000010ec3e0e2 RCTFormatError + 0
3   VwWoocommerceApp                    0x000000010ec3abb8 -[RCTExceptionsManager reportFatalException:stack:exceptionId:] + 507
4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011115036c __invoking___ + 140
5   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111150240 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 320
6   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111168c26 -[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 54
7   VwWoocommerceApp                    0x000000010ec50fe9 -[RCTModuleMethod invokeWithBridge:module:arguments:] + 602
```

Due to the above error the apps open and shows nothing.

I have searched a lot and I am new to IOS development so I didn't know how to solve the error.

If anyone knows please help.

Comment: Check it out, https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/issues/603

Comment: @Heisen-Berg I have seen this link but I think this is the error which is occurred inside the emulator and i got the above error inside the Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Libraries and add the libraries using npm and then link them to the project in the Xcode